# Rigging armature

Tags: rigging

In the below image I have my character on the right and I have an armature on the left

The armature is an FBX from mixamo which has a kicing movement, how can I apply this armature to my character? If i do join it says ''no mesh data found''

[image]

Comment: You can't join them, you have to use parenting. Select the mesh first, then the armature and hit ctrl+p. But probably you will have a better result, if you upload your character to Mixamio, then downlad it rigged.

Comment: this armature has been downloaded from mixamo, i dont want to upload character to mixamo because the textures go missing and ive used all sorts to fix it and it does not work